# В получаемом json в названии ключей встречается $. При обращении к этим полям VisualStudio выдает ошибку на знаке $. Как обратиться к этим полям?

Tags: c#, json

Есть следующий код:

```
var userLinkPicasa = "http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/" + userEmail + "?alt=json";
var myRequest = new WebClient().DownloadString(userLinkPicasa);
dynamic jsonFromPicasa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myRequest);
var userAvatar = jsonFromPicasa.entry.gphoto$thumbnail.$t;
```

С сервиса Picasa по динамической ссылке стягиваю json, из которого по Имейлу хочу вытянуть аватар пользователя. [Пример json по имейлу johndou@gmail.com](http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/johndou@gmail.com?alt=json)

В json в названия ключей встречается знак $ - `jsonFromPicasa.entry.gphoto$thumbnail.$t` и VisualStudio2017 естественно не понимает этого и после $ - выдает ошибку.

**Как же мне получить эти свойства из json??**

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, вопрос по сути одинаковый, но ответ подошел больше тот, который здесь внизу. Единственное, что мне очень пригодилось с ответа на тот вопрос и решило ситуацию(за что я благодарен) - указание строки [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)] перед объявлением класса.

Comment: Тут уже дело каждого, как он будет работать с JSON. Но я лично советую вам создать один раз нормальный "каркас" из классов, описав каждое значение вашего JSON и в него уже десериализовать. Из ответа указанного тут, вы строго привязаны к именам и если вдруг в JSON изменится к примеру `$t` на `$d` (другое имя), то вам придется везде, где вы использовали это имя пройтись и менять значение (а таких мест бывает во первых много, а во вторых - трудно отловить такие места). А так у вас будет все в классе, достаточно в 1 месте изменить атрибут и везде все будет работать и дальше как надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var userAvatar = jsonFromPicasa.entry["gphoto$thumbnail"]["$t"];
```

Comment: Ошибок нет, но userAvatar == null

Comment: Проблема в этой строке:

    dynamic jsonFromPicasa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myRequest);

Правильно так:

    var jsonFromPicasa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myRequest);

а дальше - отладчик в руки, и по шагам: топ .. топ :)

Comment: Изменил, но теперь на строку var userAvatar = 
jsonFromPicasa.entry["gphoto$thumbnail.$t"]; начало ругаться:  'object' does not contain a definition for 'entry' and no extension method 'entry' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Можно поправить так: 
var userAvatar = jsonFromPicasa["entry"]["gphoto$thumbnail.$t"];

Посмотрите классы JToken или JObject.

Comment: неа... все равно ругает. уже за Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'. Окей, посмотрю JToken или JObject. Спасибо!

Comment: Указал перед объявлением класса строку [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)] и Ваш ответ подошел, но строка dynamic jsonFromPicasa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myRequest); не мешала, так и оставил. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

1) Использовать `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

2) Перед объявлением класса указать `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]`

3) А затем можно использовать ответ выше:

```
var userAvatar = jsonFromPicasa.entry["gphoto$thumbnail"]["$t"];
```